# Why update action is invoked when submitting form with non-changed data in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I load data from two tables to the single form. On the form I create new record for model B (child) while don't change anything for model A (parent). If for model B something is entered wrongly (for example, email address without '.com') then validation error for model B is displayed. After correcting the issue (put correct email) and pressing Submit button the **update action for model A** is invoked. But in model A there were no changes! Why update action for model A is being invoked in this case? There is no data to update to the database.

*Below is more detailed explanation:*

I use one signup form to enter data for two models: Tenant and User. Any tenant will have many users. When new user wants to signup he also enters data about his tenant (company). If entered tenant doesn't exist then new tenant is created along with new user. This part is working well. The problem is when new user enters the name of tenant that already exists in the database and **ONLY if** user will enter something wrong (for example, wrong email format). If something was entered wrong then validation error (for example, Email can't be blank) occurs **AND** all previously saved users of the same tenant are also displayed as a result of `render 'new'` in TenantController.

To display only the new record for which validation error was triggered I added `<% if u.object.new_record? %>` to the signup form (maybe this is not the right way to do this?):

```
  <%= f.fields_for(:users) do |u| %>
    <% if u.object.new_record? %>
    ...
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

In this case the signup form is displayed correctly, **BUT** when I correct the cause of the validation error (for example, enter correct email) and press Save button, then update action is executed instead of create action. And this is the problem, because I don't want any user to be able to update tenant data at signup stage. At signup user should be able to create only his personal data, not update his tenant's data. Please suggest the way to do this.

Tenant model:

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :tenant
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users    

  before_validation do 
    self.status = 0 
    self.name = name_orig.upcase 
    email.downcase!
  end

  validates :name_orig, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }

  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :status, presence: true

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :tenant, inverse_of: :users

  before_validation do 
    self.status = 0
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  validates :tenant, presence: true

  VALID_USERNAME_REGEX = /\A\w+\s?\w*\z/i
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 },
                    format: { with: VALID_USERNAME_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  validates :status, presence: true

end
```

Tenant controller:

```
class TenantsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @tenant = Tenant.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @tenant = Tenant.new
    @tenant.users.build
  end

  def create
    @tenant = Tenant.find_by(name: tenant_params[:name_orig].upcase)
    if @tenant == nil
      @tenant = Tenant.new(name_orig: tenant_params[:name_orig], 
                           email: tenant_params[:email])
      @user = @tenant.users.build(tenant_params[:users_attributes]["0"])
      @tenant.save
      if @tenant.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
        redirect_to @user   # redirects to user profile
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      @user = @tenant.users.build(tenant_params[:users_attributes]["0"])
      if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
        redirect_to @user   # redirects to user profile
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end   

  private

    def tenant_params
      params.require(:tenant).permit(:name_orig, :email,
          users_attributes: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
    end
end
```

Signup form:

```
<%= form_for(@tenant) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/tenant_error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :name_orig, "Company name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name_orig, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email, "Company e-mail" %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.fields_for(:users) do |u| %>
    <% if u.object.new_record? %>
      <%= u.label :name, "User name" %>
      <%= u.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= u.label :email, "User e-mail" %>
      <%= u.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= u.label :password, "Password" %>
      <%= u.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= u.label :password_confirmation, "Password confirmation" %>
      <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first answer why your code is not working as expected.

The line under create action

> @tenant = Tenant.find_by(name: tenant_params[:name_orig].upcase)

assigns a tenant object which is already present in the database. So when you supply that @tenant object to the form_for(@tenant) the action will automatically get converted to update and not create. That is why you never faced any issue with a new tenant creation.

**Solution to this would be to set form_for url explicitly:**

> = form_for(@tenant, as: :tenant, url: tenant_path(@tenant), method: :post)

This would always send a post request to the create action.

**My two cents towards a better design**

Also, if at any point of time only one user and one tenant are going to be submitted through the form, then you can use the User as parent instead of the Tenant in the form (since User object is the primary object that is being submitted in that form, if I am right). You could think of something inverse like

```
    = form_for(@user) do |f|
      = # Fields for user goes here
      = f.fields_for(@tenant) do |t|
        = # Fields for tenant goes here
```

The advantage with this approach is that even if a tenant already exists then you could use that id within the form as tenant_id. Of course you need to change the controller to UserController and other controller code. Hope this helps.

PS: Apologies for using Haml instead of Erb.

Comment: Thank you for reply @karthikc. It seems now there is routing error:
Excerpt from server log:
...
Started POST "/tenants/19" for 82.131.65.37 at 2016-06-15 17:32:12 +0000

**ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/tenants/19"):**
...  
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (66.1ms)

Comment: My routes.rb:
`Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root               'static_pages#home'
  get 'features'  => 'static_pages#features'  
  get 'contact'   => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'    => 'tenants#new'
  resources :tenants
  resources :users
end`

Comment: Sorry for a very delayed response. Got held up in between. If you are still looking for the answer, then just by changing form_for to send a post request won't quite suffice, because the tenant record would still be present in the database and it is not a new record. That is why you are getting Routing error when you try to do a POST request on /tenants/19 url. I think it would be great if you change the form to have the user resource as a parent resource and the tenant under fields_for. Do let me know if this makes sense.